# Parsing a numeral: How do I decide whether to parse as floating point or as int?

Tags: floating-point, integer, c++17, jsonparser

I'm writing my own JSON parser and came across the problem of distinguishing between real number representation and integer number representation. So let's say I receive json value (over network) as a string which goes like this:

`"123456"`?

According to [strol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and [strtod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) I can interpret both as a floating point and decimal number. strtol expects an optional +/- sign with followed by "a sequence of digits" while strod expects a "nonempty sequence of decimal digits *optionally* containing decimal-point character". As you can see, the decimal digit is *optional* which means above example *could* be interpreted as a floating point number, even if picking it up as an integer is probably more intuitive.

So is there any consensus on how to distinguishes an int from a float in a string representation, or on what decisive characteristic should I branch?

Note: No I cannot use C++ `charconv` because I'm on an embedded system and the code bloat is just unacceptable (due to lookup tables and such).

Comment: This is neither, this is a string.

Comment: @tkausl This is about parsing so yeah its an iput string...

Comment: No, its a __json__ string, according to the `"` around it.

Comment: @tkausl What is your problem? Isn't the question clear enough? What are you getting at?

Comment: @glades: “Floating-point” means a method of representing a number in which the “point” “floats,” i.e., there is some scale that is dynamic, typically a power of a base associated with the floating-point format, such as a power of two or a power of ten. Thus, floating-point number is a representation in such a floating-point format. A string is generally not a floating-point number. A string “34” is neither an `int` nor `float`. We can call a string that represents a number a *numeral*…

Comment: … Consider the string “34.7”. This is a numeral, and it is clearly a numeral for a number that is not an integer. But neither is it a floating-point representation; there is no scale in it. So it is not correct, and can be confusing, to ask whether a string is a floating-point number or an integer. This one is neither. Perhaps you are trying to ask whether a numeral ought to be interpreted as an integer type or a floating-point type. While, clearly if the number it represents is not a mathematical integer, parsing it as an integer type will lose accuracy…

Comment: … So, if it is not a mathematical integer, you might parse it as a floating-point type. That can also lose accuracy, since no fixed-width type, whether floating-point or integer or other format, can represent all numbers. However, the loss of accuracy in converting numerals to floating-point representations is generally accepted, so it is normal to parse a numeral as a floating-point type with some rounding error…

Comment: … However, this criterion alone, the number the numeral represents is not a mathematical integer, is insufficient. Consider “3.45e2”. This represents 3.45•10^2, which is 3.45•100 = 345, which is not an integer. However, the presence of a period (or comma when that is being used as the marker for the ones place) or an exponent indicator (“e”) is commonly taken to mean the domain is some approximation of real numbers, not just integers, and so the numeral ought to be parsed as a floating-point type…

Comment: … But, as you have noticed, a numeral with no period or exponent can be represented either with an integer type or a floating-point type, subject to bounds. In that case, there is no indication of which type its original author wanted. It is plainly impossible, using the contents of the string alone, to distinguish “123456” that was originally written from an integer type from “123456” that was originally written from a floating-point type. Such a distinction can be made only if there is other information, such as a context in which the string appears.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks and yes, my question was about asking how a number _should_ be interpreted. I know how floating point numbers are represented internally, so the loss of accuracy doesn't bother me that much as there's simply no way around it. I'm much more asking if there's any consensus between library authors how different cases should be handled? If not I will just opt for parsing to float if theres a dot or exponent present.

Comment: @glades out of curiosity: what bloat/lookup tables does charconv introduce? You're already using c++, charconv is just a set of functions for parsing and stringification. I wouldn't expect them to cause code bloat.

Comment: @Wutz No it's actually quite unbearable for any resource restricted embedded system. You can watch Lavavej's talk on it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4P_kbF0EbZM It's a pitty!

Comment: could you just require your caller to describe the type of the expected structure?  e.g. something akin to `parse<struct { int i, j; float x, y, z; }>(buffer)` then the parser wouldn't have an any ambiguity in how to parse the number, and could do something sensible with numbers being incorrectly serialized in strings (e.g. as [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) does)

Answer (score 0):

Like JavaScript, JSON doesn't distinguish between integers and real numbers (as commonly represented by floats); they're all just numbers.  [Numbers in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) are all IEEE754 64bit binary floats, so you should be safe just parsing into that.

If you want to impose extra structure on some given schema then you are free to, but JSON itself doesn't know or care about this distinction.

This is known to some problems as some people want support for larger numbers than are supported by the 64bit binary floats that numbers are commonly parsed into, or even fixed format numbers like currency where floats aren't valid.  This is commonly worked around by serializing the "number" into a string first so that it doesn't get altered in the JSON parser and then deserializing manually.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up! As I'm parsing in C++ I think it's most sensible to do what users most expect which is IMHO to parse into double if it looks like a double and into int if it looks like an int. This is also what other parsers do. I'm just not quite clear on what the exact distinction is between the two or if there's any consensus between the libraries that I don't know of.

Comment: @glades I would argue that this behavior would be impractical as a user. If I want to transfer a number, say some distance, which could be 5 or 6.7 or 3.3334 etc, then your parser would store it as an integer sometimes and a floating point other times, depending on the contents. So I'd have to check both alternatives every time.

Comment: @Wutz But in this case the emitting parser could just put 5.0 as value to signal that its a real number. I would consider serializing a float to straigth "5" bad practice.

Comment: If you have control over the serializer as well as the parser, sure. But you're implicitly requiring the serializer to do that, which I'm not a fan of.